# Why is this integral that comes up during the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation equal to 0 only if the integrant is 0?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I just learned about the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation and I couldn't understand the last step which is looking at when this integral is equal to 0.
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}\right)\eta(t)dt=0$$
I understand that it is 0 when one of the factors in the argument is 0, but why is this the only case? Can't the argument inside the integral be an odd function where $f(-x) = -f(x)$? Why can't this be the case?

Answer (score 4):

It can be an odd function, but we are trying to find the case where the integral is 0 for any arbitrary function $\eta(t)$. This means that the stuff in the bracket must be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The last step uses the [Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations):

$$ \left[ \forall \eta :  \quad \int_a^b\! dx ~f(x) \eta(x) ~=~0\right]\quad\Rightarrow \quad f~=~0.  $$